# How to use gRPC in an existing Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grpc

The current web app setup is like this: there is a central server which interacts with different services through http API calls using JSON as the response object. We want to switch to using gRPC for the communication between these services to improve performance. So, can anyone help how can I use gRPC gem in my Rails application and services without changing the existing MCV ( model, controller, view) code structure.

Answer (score 1):

[gruf](https://github.com/bigcommerce/gruf) can help:

> gruf is a Ruby framework that wraps the [gRPC Ruby library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/main/src/ruby) to provide a more streamlined integration into Ruby and Ruby on Rails applications.

There's also a [demo Rails application](https://github.com/bigcommerce/gruf-demo) that can be used as a reference.

After creating your proto file, [generating the Ruby wrappers](https://github.com/bigcommerce/gruf-demo/blob/e4ffdc51fc1184375aef6482e51bccbff42c12ca/script/generate_protos.sh#L5) and wiring it up to your Rails application, you can simply `bundle exec gruf` to launch a gRPC server.

Answer (score -3):

You can't just drop in a gem and go with gRPC.

You need to define interface in .proto files first.
Then you may produce also JSON APIs to support some older/external system, see "JSON Mapping"
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json

Comment: I know that I have to define my API in protocol buffers. But I want to use the existing MVC structure and just want to change the request-response code in the client and server side to use gPRC. If there was a API to `getBlogPost` , I want the gRPC to map to the same action and controller and send the response as defined in protocol buffer. I want to know how can I achieve this.

Comment: Then you need to check if you web MVC framework support serializing data with protobuf. For example, Spring can https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services Not that you are using Protobuf, not gRPC in this case. If you want to use gRPC you need to define your protocol in .proto, as there is only one way I know to get gRPC.
For protobufs check https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md